# How to delete rows in python dataframe if condition is satisfied or not?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, delete-row

I have 3 columns in my dataframe: emails, SaleDate,Variation,LastSaleDate. 
I want to delete all rows where SaleDate != LastSaleDate, so I can remain only with one unique email where SaleDate is equal with the LastSaleDate.

I've tried a for but had an error:

```
for rows in df.itertuples(): 
    if df.SaleDate is not df.Last: 
        df.drop(axis=0)
```

```
Need to specify at least one of 'labels', 'index' or 'columns'
```

Comment: `df.loc[df['SaleDate' == df['LastSaleDate']]]` ?

Comment: df[df.SaleDate==df.Last] ?

Comment: @harvpan Cannot index with multidimensional key - error I get

Comment: @WeNYoBen the line worked but did not what it should have. I still have emails. 
I expect after running to get only one unique email where saledate is equal with LastSaleDate.

Comment: Can you provide a [MCVE] ?

Comment: @harvpan
```
email1 2019-07-12 17:16:49 1244.423710 12 2019-07-12 17:16:49 2019-07-12 17:16:49 ```

Answer (score 0):

You need to assign the output of selecting the correct row to a new variable.

```py
unique_email_df = df.loc[df['SaleDate'] == df['LastSaleDate']]
print(unique_email_df.iloc[0])
```

The `iloc[0]` print command will print out the zeroth location in your new DataFrame - this should be the one with your unique email! To print out just the email, use this:

```py
unique_email_df = df.loc[df['SaleDate'] == df['LastSaleDate']]
print(unique_email_df.emails.iloc[0])
```

Answer (score 0):

According to what you said I assume you might have duplicates in you dataframe? Try this.

```py
df[df['SaleDate'] == df['LastSaleDate']].drop_duplicates()
```